# Consults with subqueries and use of regexp

Tags: mysql

I am trying to identify users that can receive medicines produce interactions. For that  I have used this code:

```
SELECT c.user, COUNT(DISTINCT c.user) 
FROM mytable AS c
  JOIN (SELECT id_beneficiario, mes
        FROM mytable
        WHERE codigo_atc REGEXP 'C01BD01|N06AA09|J01FA10|J01MA02|J01FA09|N05AH02|L01XE06|R06AA02|A03FA03|
        L04AA27|J02AC01|N06AB03|C03CA01|N05AD01|C03AA03|J02AB02|J01MA12|N05AN01|J01XD01|J05AE04|L01XE08|
        N05AH03|N05AH04|N05AX08|J05AE03|J05AE01|C07AA07|L04AD02|M03BX02|N06AX05|J01EE03') AS d
ON c.user = d.user AND c.mes = d.mes
WHERE (c.codigo_atc REGEXP 'C01BD01|N06AA09|J01FA10|J01MA02|J01FA09|N05AH02|L01XE06|R06AA02|A03FA03|
        L04AA27|J02AC01|N06AB03|C03CA01|N05AD01|C03AA03|J02AB02|J01MA12|N05AN01|J01XD01|J05AE04|L01XE08|
        N05AH03|N05AH04|N05AX08|J05AE03|J05AE01|C07AA07|L04AD02|M03BX02|N06AX05|J01EE03')
GROUP BY c.user;
```

I am working local and the consult take too much time and apper the next Error: Error code: 2013. Lost conection to MYSQL server during query. Would be possible optimize my code to avoid the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can this work for you?

```
WHERE codigo_atc IN ('C01BD01','N06AA09','J01FA10','J01MA02','J01FA09',
                     'N05AH02','L01XE06','R06AA02','A03FA03','L04AA27',
                     'J02AC01','N06AB03','C03CA01','N05AD01', etc)
```

This `IN` clause will return true if `codigo_atc` matches any of the values in the `(list)`.

SQL is far better at set logic than it is at regular expression matching.

Comment: Thank you. The consult took 361189 sec but it worked!

Comment: That's more than four days!  You might want to consider adding some indexes to your tables.  Read this:  http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a `in` instead of a `regexp`..
Could be this is more performant

```
SELECT c.user, COUNT(DISTINCT c.user) 
FROM mytable AS c
JOIN (SELECT id_beneficiario, mes
    FROM mytable
    WHERE codigo_atc IN  ('C01BD01','N06AA09','J01FA10','J01MA02','J01FA09','N05AH02','L01XE06','R06AA02','A03FA03','
    L04AA27','J02AC01','N06AB03','C03CA01','N05AD01','C03AA03','J02AB02','J01MA12','N05AN01','J01XD01','J05AE04','L01XE08','
    N05AH03','N05AH04','N05AX08','J05AE03','J05AE01','C07AA07','L04AD02','M03BX02','N06AX05','J01EE03') AS d
ON c.user = d.user AND c.mes = d.mes
WHERE c.codigo_atc IN  ('C01BD01','N06AA09','J01FA10','J01MA02','J01FA09','N05AH02','L01XE06','R06AA02','A03FA03','
    L04AA27','J02AC01','N06AB03','C03CA01','N05AD01','C03AA03','J02AB02','J01MA12','N05AN01','J01XD01','J05AE04','L01XE08','
    N05AH03','N05AH04','N05AX08','J05AE03','J05AE01','C07AA07','L04AD02','M03BX02','N06AX05','J01EE03')
GROUP BY c.user;
```

but if you explain your related table schema and what you want obtain could is possible write a more simple query